# Efficient way to map 3D function to a meshgrid with NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, performance

I have a set of data values for a scalar 3D function, arranged as inputs `x,y,z` in an array of shape `(n,3)` and the function values `f(x,y,z)` in an array of shape `(n,)`.

**EDIT:** For instance, consider the following simple function

```
data = np.array([np.arange(n)]*3).T
F = np.linalg.norm(data,axis=1)**2
```

I would like to convolve this function with a spherical kernel in order to perform a 3D smoothing. The easiest way I found to perform this is to map the function values in a 3D spatial grid and then apply a 3D convolution with the kernel I want.

This works fine, however the part that maps the 3D function to the 3D grid is very slow, as I did not find a way to do it with NumPy only. The code below is my actual implementation, where `data` is the `(n,3)` array containing the 3D positions in which the function is evaluated, `F` is the `(n,)` array containing the corresponding values of the function and `M` is the `(N,N,N)` array that contains the 3D space grid.

```
step = 0.1

# Create meshgrid
xmin = data[:,0].min()
xmax = data[:,0].max()
ymin = data[:,1].min()
ymax = data[:,1].max()
zmin = data[:,2].min()
zmax = data[:,2].max()

x = np.linspace(xmin,xmax,int((xmax-xmin)/step)+1)
y = np.linspace(ymin,ymax,int((ymax-ymin)/step)+1)
z = np.linspace(zmin,zmax,int((zmax-zmin)/step)+1)


# Build image
M = np.zeros((len(x),len(y),len(z)))

for l in range(len(data)):
    for i in range(len(x)-1):
        if x[i] < data[l,0] < x[i+1]:
            for j in range(len(y)-1):
                if y[j] < data[l,1] < y[j+1]:
                    for k in range(len(z)-1):
                        if z[k] < data[l,2] < z[k+1]:
                            M[i,j,k] = F[l]
```

Is there a more efficient way to fill a 3D spatial grid with the values of a 3D function ?

Comment: I have not very clear the problem, it's hard to make some tests without some data sample.. but have you tried `np.meshgrid` to create de 3D grid ?

Comment: Where's the "3D function"?  All those `if` will make it hard to perform "whole-array" operations.  Those are inherently scalar.

Comment: I have updated my question, hopefully this is cleared now. By "3D function" I mean a scalar function that takes a 3D vector as input.

Comment: Note that the current code does not work due to the condition: `The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`.

Comment: Can you explain the motivation behind those `if` conditions in the loops?

Comment: @JérômeRichard This code executes without problems on my machine (just tested).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each item of data you're scanning pixels of cuboid to check if it's inside. There is an option to skip this scan. You could calculate corresponding indices of these pixels by yourself, for example:

```
data = np.array([[1, 2, 3], #14 (corner1)
                 [4, 5, 6], #77 (corner2)
                 [2.5, 3.5, 4.5], #38.75 (duplicated pixel)
                 [2.9, 3.9, 4.9], #47.63 (duplicated pixel)
                 [1.5, 2, 3]]) #15.25 (one step up from [1, 2, 3])
step = 0.5                            
data_idx = ((data - data.min(axis=0))//step).astype(int)
M = np.zeros(np.max(data_idx, axis=0) + 1)
x, y, z = data_idx.T
M[x, y, z] = F
```

Note that only one value of duplicated pixels is being mapped to M.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what this is doing precisely ? I tested it and I am not able to reach the same result as my code above.

Comment: I think the difference with the original code lies in the comparison. This method use a truncation to efficiently set the values. This is equivalent of checking `x[i] <= data[l,0] < x[i+1]` (and the same for other dimensions). The original code test if `x[i] < data[l,0] < x[i+1]`. Note the `=` for the lower bound which is missing. I am not sure this is intended but I find strange that the original code exclude values since the input only contains integers. As a result `M` is always zeros after the computation of the original code (ie. the loops do nothing)...

Comment: @user14900935's answer is basically the same, but helped me clarify your solution, thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 2):

All you need is just reshape `F[:, 3]` (only f(x, y, z)) into a grid. Hard to be more precise without sample data:

If the data is not sorted, you need to sort it:

```
F_sorted = F[np.lexsort((F[:,0], F[:,1], F[:,2]))]  # sort by x, then y, then z
```

Choose only f(x, y, z)

```
F_values = F_sorted[:, 3]
```

Finally, reshape data into a grid:

```
M = F_sorted.reshape(N, N, N)
```

Comment: Your answer provides a way to transform the values of a function of shape `(N,)` over 3D vectors forming a regular grid of shape `(N,3)` to a sorted 3D grid `(n,n,n)`, where `n=N**(1/3)`. While my question is a bit different, this might be useful to others.

Answer (score 1):

This method is faster than the original (approximatly 20x speed up):

```
step = 0.1
mins = np.min(data, axis=0)
maxs = np.max(data, axis=0)
ranges = np.floor((maxs - mins) / step + 1).astype(int)
indx = np.zeros(data.shape,dtype=int)
for i in range(3):
    x = np.linspace(mins[i], maxs[i], ranges[i])
    indx[:,i] = np.argmax(data[:,i,np.newaxis] <= (x[np.newaxis,:]), axis=1) -1
    
M = np.zeros(ranges)
M[indx[:,0],indx[:,1],indx[:,2]] = F
```

The first part sets up the required grid variables. The `argmax` function provides a simple (and fast) way to find the first true value of the broadcasted array. This produces a set of indices for x, y and z directions for each of the function values.

The resulting array `M` is not the same as that produced by the original code as the original code loses data. The logic of `y[j] < data[l,1] < y[j+1]` where `y` is a vector produced using `linspace` means the minimum and maximum values for each direction will be missed (`data[l,1]` might be equal to either `y[j]` or `y[j+1]`!). Run it with a dataset of two values each with their own coordinates and the `M` array will be all zeros.

Comment: Thank you, your solution is actually the same as @mathfux, but much clearer. Since you both provided a working solution, I will give you the bouty and accept the other solution.

Comment: Thanks for that. I guess theirs is a bit faster as it removes the loop and `linspace` commands, but glad to help.